# Arduino: Не получается считать другие rfid карты

Tags: c++, arduino, модули

Заказал себе rfid-RC522 считыватель для ардуино, подключил к меге, подключил библиотеку(MFRC522), залил скетч, но он работает только с брелком и карточкой которые шли в комплекте. Вопрос: это фича или считыватель попался плохой?

И дополнительный вопрос, как записать данные на карту с помощью это считывателя и вообще можно ли? Заранее спасибо огромное!

Comment: RFID это не то же самое что и NFC

Comment: А с чем у вас не работает?

Comment: @Unick Любые брелки и карточки кроме, тех которые шли в комплекте!От брелка домофона, до пропуска в бассейн Можете посмотреть на aliexpress что это за карточки идущие в комплекте.

Comment: Может быть существуют разные форматы, частоты. У меня такая же штука лежит, правда я её еще не попробовал.

Comment: Совершенно точно существуют и разные форматы, и разные частоты. Но RC522 это считыватель Mifare, на котором сделано большинство домофонов. Т.е. это не очень похоже на фичу.

Comment: Да, и записывать он может. При условии, что карта имеет перезаписываемую память (самые простые, типа "пропуск" и "брелок от домофона" имеют только прибитый гвоздём серийный номер) и не имеет хитрой аутентификации (насколько я понимаю, московские транспортные карты - имеют).

Comment: @AlexeyEsaulenko А не могли бы вы скинуть код перезаписи карт, ну и если не сложно считывания, может быть у меня со скетчем что-то не так!?

Comment: @Log1c0, нет, извините. Скетча у меня нет (как, впрочем, и ардуины в принципе), есть только общие представления (и куча перелопаченной документации) о всевозможных RFID.